# location error while installing matlab in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, matlab

I have downloaded matlab installer file and while running `./install` got a problem

```
manikanth@jarvis:~/Downloads/matlab_R2017a_glnxa64$ ls
activate.ini  install              license_agreement.txt  trademarks.txt
archives      installer_input.txt  patents.txt            ui
bin           install_guide.pdf    readme.txt
help          java                 sys
manikanth@jarvis:~/Downloads/matlab_R2017a_glnxa64$ sudo ./install
[sudo] password for manikanth: 
./install: 1: exec: /home/manikanth/Downloads/matlab_R2017a_glnxa64/bin/unknown/install_unix: not found
manikanth@jarvis:~/Downloads/matlab_R2017a_glnxa64$
```

Comment: Where's the file `install_unix`, is it `bin/install_unix`?

Comment: Please add the output of `uname -rm`

Comment: 4.8.0-53-generic i686

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install 64 bit version of Matlab to 32 bit Ubuntu. You either have download 32 bit matlab *(note, [it was only supported till 2012 version](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/222489-is-matlab-supported-on-32-bit-linux))*, or install Ubuntu 64 bit *(which is highly recommended, if you CPU supports it — and it does unless it's either ancient or some of Atoms)*.